Can consuming durian together with alcohol harm or even kill you?
In Singapore and Malaysia (and possibly other countries), it is a well-known "fact" that you shouldn't consume durian together with alcohol because it can kill you.
This is sometimes dismissed as a myth or urban legend (e.g. 1, 2).

Singh (1941) reported

mysterious deaths occurring sometimes following the consumption of durians and alcohol.

Maninang, Lizada, and Gemmaa (2009) suggest a possible mechanism:

The durian–alcohol anecdote has been sheltered with over 250 years of belief. Few attempts to validate the interaction have vaguely disproved the alleged antagonism between durian and ethanol (Nilveses & Seangsirinavin, 1986; Ogle & Teh, 1969, 1971; Techapaitoon & Sim, 1973). None of these in vivo studies, however, considered the possible interference of some components in durian on the enzymatic system for detoxifying alcohol. To our knowledge, this is the first attempt to explore the molecular basis of the durian–alcohol anecdote and no other literature has yet linked a fruit to adverse reactions that may arise upon interaction with alcohol. ...
yALDH significantly lost (P < 0.05) enzymatic activity in the presence of durian fruit extract at all concentrations used

Ho and Bhat (2015):

the sulphur content of durian is reported to have inhibitory characteristic on ALDH activity and can be mortal in person who consume durian and drink alcohol simultaneously


So, can consuming durian together with alcohol harm or even kill you?

There's a related post on our [medicalsciences.se] site, Should one avoid consuming durians when drinking alcohol? which pretty much answers this one.
